# Unchecked cast involving wildcard types

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

Can somebody explain why this is an unchecked cast

```
static void foo(Collection<? extends Number> collection) {
    List<? extends Number> list = (List<? extends Number>) collection;
}
```

but this isn't?

```
static void bar(List<? extends Number> list) {
    Collection<? extends Number> collection = (Collection<? extends Number>) list;
}
```

I think it's got something to do with captures, but I'd like a clear explanation.

**Edit**

I realise that this is a badly worded question, and that the correct answer is "because `List` extends `Collection`". However in IntelliJ it's generating a warning that you don't usually get when casting to a more specific type. From the comments below it seems that this may simply be a bug in IntelliJ. The exact warning is in the comments below (for some reason I can't reproduce it here). I don't get a warning on any of the following

```
static void foo(Collection<Number> collection) {
    List<Number> list = (List<Number>) collection;
}

static <T> void foo(Collection<T> collection) {
    List<T> list = (List<T>) collection;
}

static void foo(Collection<?> collection) {
    List<?> list = (List<?>) collection;
}
```

Comment: what makes you think it's unchecked? If you compile that with `-Xlint:unchecked` you don't get any warnings about unchecked casts.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's just IntelliJ then. The exact message is `Unchecked cast: 'java.util.Collection<capture<? extends java.lang.Number>>' to 'java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Number>'`

Comment: And it doesn't give you the same for a cast from `Object` to `String`?

Comment: No. It doesn't give me the same when I remove the wildcards either.

Answer (score 0):

Because the cast from `List<? extends Number>` to `List<? extends Number>` is a downcast and would normally require a check of the object's type at runtime. However, the runtime environment cannot check, if the type parameter is really a class that extents `Number`. That information isn't available at runtime, Java Generics ("type parameters") only exist in the static Java type system, they don't affect the compiled code. The only thing about the cast that can be checked at runtime is therefore, if the `Collection` is a `List`.

The other case is a simple upcast, where no runtime information is necessary. You can check at compile time, that this cast will always work. The lack of information about the type parameter at runtime is therefore irrelevant.